# Why TortoiseSVN forces me to close each commit dialog with OK button?

Tags: user-interface, button, tortoisesvn

This seems to be a trivial question, but this issue really, really drives me crazy.

I'm closing EVERY window in my Windows using "red x" button. I'm rather quick user of computers, typing around 300 characters per minute and doing similar number of clicks. Having to remember that I have to do a special exception for TortoiseSVN makes every my day really bad.

Why TortoiseSVN authors forces me to use "OK" button? What is the damn logic behind writing special code to block user from using "x" button to close each commit results window? Anyone knows the answers?

And the most important: How can I change it? How can I turn my favorite SVN client back to normal and be able to close each of its window with "x" button, as I do in ALL Windows applications?

Comment: To answer the last question: by filing a bug against TortoiseSVN explaining your reasoning?

Comment: @&s.m.: That would be the first thing to do. But since this isn't probably a bug, only wanted feature, I asked here, if maybe someone knows the logic which lead to something like this? With this logic I may see things in different ligth and filling bug-report may turn over to be unnecessary.

Comment: Most windows in TortoiseSVN can be dismissed by hitting escape. The commit dialog can be OKed with (as I recall) Ctrl-Return or dismissed with escape.

Comment: Great! But I still want to dismiss it with red "x" button. And it sitll anoying me, that someone is forcing me to do something. Especially, when there is no reason for that.

Comment: See here: http://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/issues/detail?id=317

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks (+1). This explains everything. So, it is a bug! :] Please, place this comment as full answer, so I can voteup and select it. This is direct answer to my question (Why? Because it is a bug!), so you should receive full reputation reward for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Stefan told you, [it is a bug](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/issues/detail?id=317). It's marked as "fixed", so to solve your problem, I think that all you need is to update your TortoiseSVN to the newest version! :}

Comment: A good lesson for me, to seek bug-tracker for TortoiseSVN (or other product) BEFORE asking a bit dumb questions! :] Thank you (+1).